# Unable to export 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories' schema using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

Am trying to export ARM template for a resourcegroup where in i have Azure data factory, but when using "Export-AzureRmResourceGroup" it throws a warning as below and none of ADF schema is downloaded in that template. is there a way to download ADF template using powershell??

```
Export-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName ****************
WARNING: ExportTemplateCompletedWithErrors : Export template operation completed with errors. Some resources were not exported. Please see details for more information.
WARNING: ResourceTypeSchemaNotFound : The schema of resource type 'Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces' is not available. Resources of this type will not be exported to the template.
WARNING: ResourceTypeSchemaNotFound : The schema of resource type '**Microsoft.DataFactory/factories**' is not available. Resources of this type will not be exported to the template.
WARNING: ResourceTypeSchemaNotFound : The schema of resource type 'Microsoft.Portal/dashboards' is not available. Resources of this type will not be exported to the template.
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [there](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/06b0a24a-c088-4ab1-ace0-5957bb4c2440/data-factory-resource-provider-wont-create-template-from-resource-group?forum=AzureDataFactory), DataFactory template export is not supported yet.

BUT, there is a solution which we've used in our CI/CD.

First, we've created a dummy generic template for the datafactory (see the steps below), and then used either ARM template exported from the datafactory template or adf_publish (see the notes below) branch to update and finalize the datafactory.

To create a dummy datafactory template:

1. On the portal try to create a dummy datafactory, and click on "Automation options" (**instead** of "Create")

[image]

2. This will create an empty datafactory ARM template, which then you can use for your pipelines. Now just click on the "Download" button and store the dummy template somewhere.

[image]

3. Afterwards you can use that template to create a new dummy datafactory if it doesn't exist, and then update it with the real ARM templates provided by either the "Export ARM Template" button inside the datafactory, or the adf_publ

**Notes**:
1. We came to this solution as the ARM templates which were provided* by the azure portal, were **not** including the Datafactory resource itself, because of which deployment to a new Resource Group was **FAILING**.
So, we had to create a dummy DataFactory first, and then update it with actual DataFactory template.
2. By saying "provided* by the azure portal" we mean the ARM templates which are provided when you open the DF and click on "ARM Template" > "Export ARM template", or the one published in adf_publish branch
3. For creating CI/CD we used the other steps mentioned [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment)

Comment: for me this does not work either. We can manually create ADF and then ARM template pipeline will not work. But if we use export template then it works . So portal works pipeline does not work

Answer (score 1):

This is because those "ResourceTypeSchemas" are not available to use in ARM templates. It doesn't matter if you go into the portal and try to get the resource template. It will show the same error there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You get exactly the same thing when you are trying to do via Azure directly:
[image: Data factory ARM template generation]

However there's a template defined by Microsoft for almost any object, which you can access [in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template), so if you're starting from scratch, this can be a good starting point to create your template.

If you already have something defined in your existing data factory, then you just need to export ARM template directly from your data factory and merge extracted template with the one from Microsoft documentation.

[image: how to export already existing data factory arm template]

For this to work you need to include two nodes, because the yare not currently included in this export functionality: for generating the data factory itself

```
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      }
    }
```

and you will also probably need a template for storage account

```
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2"
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

If all you need is the template, and if you are trying to download via PowerShell, then I assume you have access to that RG.So navigate to `Azure Portal->Resource Group` ( that has the ADF or any resource that you need. From the left nav bar , you'll find this `Automation Script`[image] .

Click on it and the template will appear. From here, you can `download` the template directly